# how to optimize this sql

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, triggers

This is a *trigger*:

```
create trigger tg1
after insert on table1
for each row
begin
update table2 set amount=if(isnull(amount),0,amount)+1 where t2_id=new.t1_id;
end;
```

how to optimize : `amount=if(isnull(amount),0,amount)+1`

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a bit cleaner :

```
amount=IFNULL(amount,0)+1
```